# Python script with multiprocessing hangs inside a for loop

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.6

I'm working with tensorflow-gpu==1.8.0 and keras==2.1.6 in anaconda3 python 3.6.5 env, windows 10, cpu == i7 8700, gpu == 1080. And I'm using multiprocessing module to paralalize my script. And I have a for i in range(EPS) loop in run() method, Class Optimizer and Environment. So, the problem is that when I run the script with EPS = 500 or any number less then that it works fine. But if I try running it with EPS = 1000 or more it just hangs in the very beginning, stops printing anything to cmd and cpu usage goes to idle, but RAM usage doesn't change. And I'm sure that it reaches this for loop before hanging, and it even sucessfully loops trough before hanging. I tried running it on different windows 10 machine, but it didn't change the situation. I also tried running it with pure python, not conda, also nothing. It is actually really weird how a for loop can make a script hang. I think it could be potentially related to Manager class or dead lock.

I tried running my script with EPS = 7200 using this comand: python -m trace --trace myscript.py and this is what I got (small part of it):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 223, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_name(data['init_main_from_name'])
  File 

"C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 249, in _fixup_main_from_name
    alter_sys=True)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 93, in _run_module_code
    with _TempModule(mod_name) as temp_module, _ModifiedArgv0(fname):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 55, in __enter__
    sys.argv[0] = self.value
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Here's my code

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, brain, eps_start, eps_end, eps_steps):
        self.eps_start = eps_start
        self.eps_end = eps_end
        self.eps_steps = eps_steps
        self.brain = brain

        self.memory = []  # used for n_step return
        self.R = 0.

    def getEpsilon(self, frames):
        if frames.value >= self.eps_steps:
            return self.eps_end
        else:
            return self.eps_start + frames.value * (self.eps_end - self.eps_start) / self.eps_steps  # linearly interpolate

    def act(self, s, frames, lock):
        eps = self.getEpsilon(frames)
        lock.acquire()
        frames.value = frames.value + 1
        lock.release()
        if random() < eps:
            return np.random.randint(0, NUM_ACTIONS - 1)

        else:
            s = np.array([s])
            p = self.brain.predict(s)[0][0]

            # a = np.argmax(p)
            a = np.random.choice(NUM_ACTIONS, p=p)

            return a

    def train(self, s, a, r, s_, lock):
        def get_sample(memory, n):
            s, a, _, _ = memory[0]
            _, _, _, s_ = memory[n - 1]

            return s, a, self.R, s_

        a_cats = np.zeros(NUM_ACTIONS)  # turn action into one-hot representation
        a_cats[a] = 1

        self.memory.append((s, a_cats, r, s_))

        self.R = (self.R + r * GAMMA_N) / GAMMA

        if s_ is None:
            while len(self.memory) > 0:
                n = len(self.memory)
                s, a, r, s_ = get_sample(self.memory, n)
                self.brain.train_push(s, a, r, s_, lock)

                self.R = (self.R - self.memory[0][2]) / GAMMA
                self.memory.pop(0)

            self.R = 0

        if len(self.memory) >= N_STEP_RETURN:
            s, a, r, s_ = get_sample(self.memory, N_STEP_RETURN)
            self.brain.train_push(s, a, r, s_, lock)

            self.R = self.R - self.memory[0][2]
            self.memory.pop(0)


class Environment:
    def __init__(self, brain, data, testing=False, eps_start=EPS_START, eps_end=EPS_STOP,
                 eps_steps=EPS_STEPS):
        self.testing = testing
        self.env = Market(1000, data, testing=testing)
        self.agent = Agent(brain, eps_start, eps_end, eps_steps)

    def run_episode(self, lock, frames):
        s = self.env.reset()
        done = False
        result = None
        while not done:
            # time.sleep(THREAD_DELAY)
            a = self.agent.act(s, frames, lock)
            s_, r, done, info = self.env.step(a)

            if done:  # terminal state
                s_ = None
                result = info

            self.agent.train(s, a, r, s_, lock)

            s = s_
        lock.acquire()
        print("Total reward:", self.env.total)
        lock.release()

        data = pd.DataFrame(result, index=[frames.value], dtype=float)
        data.to_csv(PATH_HISTORY, mode='a', header=False)

    def run(self, lock, frames):
        for i in range(EPS):
            self.run_episode(lock, frames)
            if self.testing: break


class Optimizer:
    def __init__(self, brain):
        self.brain = brain

    def run(self, lock, frames):
        for i in range(EPS):
            self.brain.optimize(lock)


class Brain:
    train_queue = [[], [], [], [], []]  # s, a, r, s', s' terminal mask

    def __init__(self, saved_model=True, path='model.h5'):
        self.session = tf.Session()
        K.set_session(self.session)
        K.manual_variable_initialization(True)

        if saved_model:
            self.model = self.init_model(path=path)
        else:
            self.model = self._build_model()

        self.graph = self._build_graph(self.model)

        self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        self.default_graph = tf.get_default_graph()

        self.default_graph.finalize()    # avoid modifications

    def _build_model(self):

        l_input = Input(batch_shape=(None, NUM_STATE))
        l_dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')(l_input)
        l_dense = Dense(256, activation='relu')(l_dense)
        l_dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')(l_dense)

        out_actions = Dense(NUM_ACTIONS, activation='softmax')(l_dense)
        out_value = Dense(1, activation='linear')(l_dense)

        model = Model(inputs=[l_input], outputs=[out_actions, out_value])
        model._make_predict_function()   # have to initialize before threading

        return model

    def init_model(self, path):
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            model = load_model(path)
            model._make_predict_function()
            return model
        else:
            print('WARN! Given path does not exist')
            return self._build_model()

    def save_model(self, path='model.h5'):
        self.model.save(path)

    def _build_graph(self, model):
        s_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, NUM_STATE))
        a_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, NUM_ACTIONS))
        r_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1)) # not immediate, but discounted n step reward

        p, v = model(s_t)

        log_prob = tf.log(tf.reduce_sum(p * a_t, axis=1, keepdims=True) + 1e-10)
        advantage = r_t - v

        loss_policy = - log_prob * tf.stop_gradient(advantage)  # maximize policy
        loss_value = LOSS_V * tf.square(advantage)  # minimize value error
        entropy = LOSS_ENTROPY * tf.reduce_sum(p * tf.log(p + 1e-10), axis=1, keepdims=True)   # maximize entropy (regularization)

        loss_total = tf.reduce_mean(loss_policy + loss_value + entropy)

        optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE, decay=.99)
        minimize = optimizer.minimize(loss_total)

        return s_t, a_t, r_t, minimize

    def optimize(self, lock):
        if len(self.train_queue[0]) < MIN_BATCH:
            # time.sleep(0)   # yield
            return

        lock.acquire()
        if len(self.train_queue[0]) < MIN_BATCH: # more thread could have passed without lock
            return # we can't yield inside lock
        s, a, r, s_, s_mask = self.train_queue
        self.train_queue = [[], [], [], [], []]
        lock.release()

        s = np.vstack(s)
        a = np.vstack(a)
        r = np.vstack(r)
        s_ = np.vstack(s_)
        s_mask = np.vstack(s_mask)

        if len(s) > 5*MIN_BATCH:
            lock.acquire()
            print(f'Optimizer alert! Minimizing batch of {len(s)}')
            lock.release()

        v = self.predict(s_)[1]
        r = r + GAMMA_N * v * s_mask  # set v to 0 where s_ is terminal state

        s_t, a_t, r_t, minimize = self.graph
        self.session.run(minimize, feed_dict={s_t: s, a_t: a, r_t: r})

    def train_push(self, s, a, r, s_, lock):

        lock.acquire()
        self.train_queue[0].append(s)
        self.train_queue[1].append(a)
        self.train_queue[2].append(r)

        if s_ is None:
            self.train_queue[3].append(NONE_STATE)
            self.train_queue[4].append(0.)
        else:
            self.train_queue[3].append(s_)
            self.train_queue[4].append(1.)

        lock.release()

    def predict(self, s):
        with self.default_graph.as_default():
            p, v = self.model.predict(s)
            return p, v


np.seterr(all='raise')


def run(obj, lock, frames):
    obj.run(lock, frames)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    env_threads, opt_threads = [], []

    frames = Value('i', 0)

    m = Manager()
    lock = m.Lock()

    BaseManager.register('Brain', Brain)
    manager = BaseManager()
    manager.start()
    brain = manager.Brain()

    env_test = Environment(brain=brain, testing=True, data=test_data, eps_start=0., eps_end=0.)

    envs = [Environment(brain=brain, data=train_data) for i in range(THREADS)]
    opts = [Optimizer(brain=brain) for i in range(OPTIMIZERS)]

    for env in envs:
        p = Process(target=run, args=[env, lock, frames])
        p.start()
        env_threads.append(p)

    for opt in opts:
        p = Process(target=run, args=[opt, lock, frames])
        p.start()
        opt_threads.append(p)

    for p in env_threads:
        p.join()

    for p in opt_threads:
        p.join()

    print('finished in ', time.time() - start)
```

If anyone had something similar or anything that could be relevant please let me know, since I've been strugling with this issue for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I think it was due to this line:

```
 if len(self.train_queue[0]) < MIN_BATCH:
      return
```

Cuz we can't return inside a lock